# How to set windows 7 like look of desktop application (c#.net)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

my client is asking for windows 7 like look for my desktop application (developed in c#.net). please tell me how can i set such theame for my application so that i would look like windows 7... please tell me if any such a controls/theme available... (open source is prefered)... please help me out.. i am using .net framework 3.5... and i am not familer with WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be the [DevExpress Winforms/WPF components](http://www.devexpress.com/), they look awesome, have great support and are quite easy to use.

Comment: cant use wpf.. please provide me some other solution

Comment: Hey, DevExpress does offer a set of WinForms controls should you not want to/ can't use the WPF controls.

Check out: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/

Answer (score 1):

First of all: use WPF, they look a lot better.

Second of all: The WPF Toolkit contains lots of useful stuff to create nice UIs.

Lastly: in .NET 4.0 you can create jumplists, icon overlays and stuff like that. If you're using 3.5 then there is the Windows API codepack which you can use for these features.